# Apache Spark on Yarn error

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have Spark 1.1.1 running on top of a Hadoop 2.4.1 three node cluster. When I type 
`./spark-shell --master yarn-client`, 
I get the following message repeatedly and this message keeps going on:

```
15/01/09 09:48:48 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application report from ASM:
         appMasterRpcPort: -1
         appStartTime: 1420796814009
         yarnAppState: ACCEPTED

15/01/09 09:48:49 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application report from ASM:
         appMasterRpcPort: -1
         appStartTime: 1420796814009
         yarnAppState: ACCEPTED

15/01/09 09:48:50 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application report from ASM:
         appMasterRpcPort: -1
         appStartTime: 1420796814009
         yarnAppState: ACCEPTED
```

Someone please help. I have tried looking everywhere but no result. This is the full message that is displayed:

```
  ....
    15/01/09 09:53:39 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 53539.
    15/01/09 09:53:40 INFO server.Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
    15/01/09 09:53:40 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
    15/01/09 09:53:40 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
    15/01/09 09:53:40 INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at `http://master:4040`
    15/01/09 09:53:40 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    --args is deprecated. Use --arg instead.
    15/01/09 09:53:41 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at master/172.31.0.206:8040
    15/01/09 09:53:42 INFO yarn.Client: Got cluster metric info from ResourceManager, number of NodeManagers: 0
    15/01/09 09:53:42 INFO yarn.Client: Max mem capabililty of a single resource in this cluster 8192
    15/01/09 09:53:42 INFO yarn.Client: Preparing Local resources
    15/01/09 09:53:42 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading file:/home/ubuntu/spark/assembly/target/scala-2.10/spark-assembly-1.1.1-hadoop2.4.1.jar to hdfs://master:9000/user/ubuntu/.sparkStaging/application_1420794003755_0004/spark-assembly-1.1.1-hadoop2.4.1.jar
    15/01/09 09:48:48 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application report from ASM:
             appMasterRpcPort: -1
             appStartTime: 1420796814009
             yarnAppState: ACCEPTED

    15/01/09 09:48:49 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application report from ASM:
             appMasterRpcPort: -1
             appStartTime: 1420796814009
             yarnAppState: ACCEPTED

    15/01/09 09:48:50 INFO cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Application report from ASM:
             appMasterRpcPort: -1
             appStartTime: 1420796814009
             yarnAppState: ACCEPTED
```

Comment: The messages are expected. It's reporting the progress. Any other error?

Comment: How long does it go for?

Comment: It just keeps going on for a really long time. I had to use Ctrl+C to break the rolling message.

Comment: This indicates that YARN accepted your application into a queue but that it's not running yet. Something else may be running already (using up the needed capacity). Otherwise, are you requesting more resources than there are available on the cluster? Do all nodes show up on the YARN dashboard?

Comment: Yeah, all the nodes can be seen on the dashboard. I am guessing it is mostly a memory issue.

Comment: yarn application -list